# Nodejs mp3 streaming

Tags: node.js, audio, streaming

I am try to create a small nodejs server that will take requests that will stream audio.
I'm currently using 0.10.5 api. I must admit I am a newbie to nodejs. I'm not sure how to edit this code to successfully stream audio.

```
        var http = environment.http;

        //Steaming Audio
        var path = environment.path,
            util = environment.util,
            url = environment.url;

        http.createServer(function (request, response) {

            var queryData = url.parse(request.url, true).query;
            window.console.log(queryData);
            if (!queryData.hasOwnProperty('file')) {
                response.writeHead(404, {
                    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
                });
                response.end();
                window.console.log('In here');

            } else {
                window.console.log('In here2');
                var filePath = queryData.file;
                var extension = self.getExtension(filePath);
                var acceptedExtensions = ['mp3', 'wav', 'aiff'];
                if ($.inArray(extension, acceptedExtensions) == -1) {
                    response.writeHead(404, {
                        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
                    });
                    response.end();
                }

                var stat = environment.fs.statSync(filePath);
                response.writeHead(200, {
                    'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg',
                    'Content-Length': stat.size
                });
                //window.console.log(filePath);
                var readStream = environment.fs.createReadStream(filePath);
                //var readable = new require('stream').Readable();
                readStream.pipe(response);

            }


        }).listen(10000);
```

When I make a request
`http://localhost:10000/?file=/Users/acasanova/Music/Cass%20Beats/45th.mp3`
The console shows "In here2" and then "In here". I'm trying to figure out why it seems to fulfill the request twice and why the audio isn't being streamed.

Comment: Looks like my getExtension was the culprit but now after my first request to stream audio works..all subsequent requests stream the same audio. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

One very simple reason why you are getting the first response 'in here' is probably because your browser is looking for a favicon file, which your node application responds with a 404. This is what I have generally observed when you try to write a simple app in node.js.

As to why the audio isn't streaming, I have to look into it properly. But I don't know why you are trying to set a content-length as node.js httpServer, as it supports writing chunked responses (`Transfer-Encoding: chunked`) by default (which is what you need for streaming). There is something obviously wrong with this approach, but I will have to look into it properly to give you a definate answer.